# Android check if text input (time) matches the format

Tags: android, time, kotlin

I have two text fields that have as an input time (mm:ss)
How do I create a check (with a Toast, I know how to make toast xD) to see if it matches that format, if not then pass on the toast? Been trying but didn't manage anything.

I don't know if you need more than this, but here is where I pass them:

```
val time = findViewById<NumberPicker>(R.id.time) as TextView
    val distance = findViewById<NumberPicker>(R.id.distance) as TextView
    val pace = findViewById<NumberPicker>(R.id.pace) as TextView


    calculate.setOnClickListener {

        when {

            time.text.isEmpty() && (distance.text.isNotEmpty() && pace.text.isNotEmpty()) -> calculatePace(null, distance.text.toString(), pace.text.toString())

            distance.text.isEmpty() && (time.text.isNotEmpty() && pace.text.isNotEmpty()) -> calculatePace(time.text.toString(), null, pace.text.toString())

            pace.text.isEmpty() && (time.text.isNotEmpty() && distance.text.isNotEmpty()) -> calculatePace(time.text.toString(), distance.text.toString(), null)

            else -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please check all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
```

Is this enough, or do you need the function where I use them?
Thanks

=========

**EDIT:**

I tried to create this function but how do I pass my edit ext in here now? Is it correct as well?

```
fun isTimeValid(time: String?): Boolean {
    val expression = "^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]\$"
    val pattern = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
    val matcher = pattern.matcher(time)
    return matcher.matches()
}
```

Comment: I think that may be there is a function to turn a string to a datetime format and it works if the format is right and throws an exception if the format is wrong...if there is not such a function may be casting the string to DateTime will do the same

Comment: I pass down the format like this val timeString = String.format("%02d:%02d",minutes, seconds)

Answer (score 0):

### try this.

```
 if (!Constants.isStringEmpty(str_time)&&isTimeValid(str_time)){
        //// TODO: 10/6/2017  
    }else {
        if (Constants.isStringEmpty(str_time)){
            edt_email.requestFocus();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Enter Time.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(!isTimeValid(str_time)){
            edt_email.requestFocus();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Enter Valid Time.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

 public static boolean isTimeValid(String time) {
    boolean isValid = false;
    String expression = "^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$";
    CharSequence inputStr = time;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        isValid = true;
    }
    return isValid;
 }
```